# EF and WPF Datagrid binding issue

Tags: entity-framework, wpfdatagrid

Is it possible to change the name of the server the EF connect to on the fly?

I have the same database on 5 servers (different environments, Dev, Test, UAT...) and would like to write a dashboard application to extract the same information from each server in turn by just selecting the environment from a DDL.

I am using Entity Framework 4/WPF/C#. The new ObservableCollection(context.EntitySet) is bound to the WPF DataGrid in XAML. This works fine.
the xaml grid binding is as follow

```
<grid:RadGridView ItemsSource="{Binding EPolicies}" IsReadOnly="True" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected" RowIndicatorVisibility="Collapsed" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
```

in the view model I call the following code

```
             entities = new EpolicyEntities(environmentConnStr);
            customTexts = new ObservableCollection<C_CustomTextType>(from i in entities.C_CustomTextType select i);
            languages = new ObservableCollection<C_Language>(from i in entities.C_Language select i);
            userTypes = new ObservableCollection<C_UserType>(from i in entities.C_UserType select i);
            EPolicies = new ObservableCollection<EPolicy>(from e in entities.EPolicies select e);
```

entities is the ObjectContext representing the database that I connect to

The first time it works fine but the second time even thoguh I can see the new values in the EPolicies object, the grid is not being refreshed as I would want
EPolicies is a property defined as below
        public ObservableCollection EPolicies
        {
            get { return ePolicies; }
            set
            {
                ePolicies = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(() => EPolicies);
            }
        }
Can somebody help me please?
thanks

Anyone done this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay I found out.

The issue was that the property

```
public ObservableCollection EPolicies {                     

  get { return ePolicies; } 

  set {
      ePolicies = value; OnPropertyChanged(() => EPolicies); 
  }
}
```

is calling the `OnpropertyChanged` but not the `Base.OnPropertyChanged`.
Not sure why it works that way might be that the event is not being bubbled up.
Does anybody has an answer?